# Compile and run CM 10.2 on simulator (GOLDFISH)

Tags: android, build, cyanogenmod

I want to build and run CyanongenMod 10.2 on simulator. First of all, my developer machine is ok (it builds CM 10.2 for crespo, a CM fork for Motorola Defy...CM 10.1 for samsung p4 tablet).

In order to build CM 10.2 for simulator I do the following steps:
breakfast goldfish: download kernel and goldfish releated stuff
mka: do a full build
The build is done: all the .img file are in the $OUT folder. Seems all ok...but if I run "emulator -show-kernel" it blocks with a lot of error :

```
init: could not import file '/init.carrier.rc' from '/init.rc'
init: do_chown: Could not access /selinux/booleans
init: do_chown: Could not access /sys/fs/selinux/booleans
init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
yaffs: dev is 32505856 name is "mtdblock0"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.0, "mtdblock0"
block 1177 is bad
block 1182 is bad
yaffs: dev is 32505857 name is "mtdblock1"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.1, "mtdblock1"
yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
yaffs: dev is 32505858 name is "mtdblock2"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.2, "mtdblock2"
yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
fs_mgr: Cannot mount filesystem on /dev/block/mtdblock0 at /system
init: fs_mgr_mount_all returned an error
yaffs tragedy: no more erased blocks
[....]
yaffs tragedy: no more erased blocks
init: cannot find '/system/bin/sysinit', disabling 'sysinit'
init: Unable to open persistent property directory /data/property errno: 2
init: cannot find '/system/bin/servicemanager', disabling 'servicemanager'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/vold', disabling 'vold'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/qemu-props', disabling 'qemu-props'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/auditd', disabling 'auditd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/netd', disabling 'netd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/debuggerd', disabling 'debuggerd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/rild', disabling 'ril-daemon'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/surfaceflinger', disabling 'surfaceflinger'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/app_process', disabling 'zygote'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/drmserver', disabling 'drm'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/mediaserver', disabling 'media'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/installd', disabling 'installd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/keystore', disabling 'keystore'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/handle_compcache', disabling 'compcache'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/qemud', disabling 'qemud'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/logcat', disabling 'goldfish-logcat'
init: cannot find '/system/etc/init.goldfish.sh', disabling 'goldfish-setup'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/sh', disabling 'console'
```

It seems to be an error with EXT4 image file: emulator does not accept EXT4 filesystem but only yaffs?

The question is simple: is it possible to run a CM build on simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I have same issue with you, then I run command:

```
mkyaffs2image -f out/target/product/generic/system out/target/product/generic/system_yaffs2.img

emulator -kernel out/target/product/generic/zImage  -system out/target/product/generic/system_yaffs2.img -ramdisk out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img -data out/target/product/generic/data_yaffs2.img -partition-size 1024  -show-kernel -verbose
```

wait several minutes, the emulator can be launched.

But the ril service seems coredump, so 3G network won't work. I am looking for how to fix this.

Comment: Thank you. Now the emulator starts with the rotating CM boot logo, but it is blocked on the boot animation

Answer (score 0):

I try with another way:
*) edit the system/core/rootdir/init.rc file and change the mount command:

```
on fs
# mount mtd partitions
    # Mount /system rw first to give the filesystem a chance to save a checkpoint
    mount ext4 mtd@system /system
    mount ext4 mtd@system /system ro remount
    mount ext4 mtd@userdata /data nosuid nodev
    mount ext4 mtd@cache /cache nosuid nodev
```

The output is :

```
fs_mgr: Cannot mount filesystem on /dev/block/mtdblock0 at /system
init: fs_mgr_mount_all returned an error
init: cannot find '/system/bin/sysinit', disabling 'sysinit'
init: Unable to open persistent property directory /data/property errno: 2
init: cannot find '/system/bin/servicemanager', disabling 'servicemanager'
```

*) using the previous init.rc file, compile a new goldfish kernel from GIT sources and edit the .config file

```
CONFIG_EXT4_FS=y
CONFIG_EXT4_USE_FOR_EXT23=y
CONFIG_EXT4_FS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_EXT4_FS_SECURITY=y
```

Then run the emulator with "emulator -show-kernel -kernel ~/goldfish/arch/arm/boot/zImage"

The output is:

```
init: could not import file '/init.carrier.rc' from '/init.rc'
init (1): /proc/1/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1/oom_score_adj instead.
init: do_chown: Could not access /selinux/booleans
init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
goldfish_nand_read: invalid read, start 0, len 200, dev_size 21560000, write_size 800
end_request: I/O error, dev mtdblock0, sector 2
EXT4-fs (mtdblock0): unable to read superblock
goldfish_nand_read: invalid read, start 0, len 200, dev_size c200000, write_size 800
end_request: I/O error, dev mtdblock1, sector 2
EXT4-fs (mtdblock1): unable to read superblock
goldfish_nand_read: invalid read, start 0, len 200, dev_size 4000000, write_size 800
end_request: I/O error, dev mtdblock2, sector 2
EXT4-fs (mtdblock2): unable to read superblock
goldfish_nand_read: invalid read, start 0, len 200, dev_size 21560000, write_size 800
end_request: I/O error, dev mtdblock0, sector 2
EXT4-fs (mtdblock0): unable to read superblock
fs_mgr: Cannot mount filesystem on /dev/block/mtdblock0 at /system
init: fs_mgr_mount_all returned an error
init: cannot find '/system/bin/sysinit', disabling 'sysinit'
```